# Angular 2 Highcharts how to use value from click events in component?

Tags: javascript, typescript, highcharts, components, angular2-highcharts

Am trying to access the value of the columns in my highchart stacked bar chart with the click event like this:

```
plotOptions: {
      series: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
          events: {
            click:function(event){
              console.log(event);
              //this.filter.emit([this.category, this.serie.name]);
              alert('Name: '+ this.category + ', Value: ' + this.y + ', Series :' + this.series.name);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

So far so good, but I need to use those values in my compoenent. The problem is that the 'this' keyword refers to the Point object and I dont see how i can use the parameters of my component if can't refer to them with 'this.'...

Is there a way to access both scope(my component and the Point object) in the function triggered by the click?

Comment: Could you please post live example of your chart, like plunker?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/TypOX9XZvnjGxrt7J32P?p=preview if you need anything else please tell me and ill try to answer as quickly as possible

Comment: bind 'this' to the function dynamically with bind method https://plnkr.co/edit/jtuyYXoYnDbTRwaIfpg0?p=preview

Comment: Wow thank you sir! I think these guy needed the same tip https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045016/call-an-angular-component-method-when-we-click-on-highchart-series